# With go_router, how should I configure my router to create a Twitter like navigation using ShellRoute?

Tags: flutter

I'm trying to create a navigation like Twitter where there are 2 tabs in the bottom navigation bar, the home tab and the search tab. In the home tab, there is a list of tweets and when the user clicks on a tweet, it navigates to the details screen of the clicked tweet. Similarly, in the search tab, the user can search for tweets with some keywords and get a list of tweets and tapping a tweet navigates the user to its details screen. So the user can navigate to a details page in both the home tab and the search tab.

I wrote a router for this scenario, modifying the sample code from [ShellRoute](https://pub.dev/documentation/go_router/latest/go_router/ShellRoute-class.html) as follows:

```dart
// I used the ShellRoute to create a persistent navigation bar

final GlobalKey<NavigatorState> _rootNavigatorKey =
    GlobalKey<NavigatorState>();

  final GoRouter _router = GoRouter(
    navigatorKey: _rootNavigatorKey,
    initialLocation: '/home',
    routes: [
      ShellRoute(
        navigatorKey: _shellNavigatorKey,
        builder: (context, state, child) {
          return ScaffoldWithNavBar(child: child);
        },
        routes: [
          GoRoute(
            path: '/home',
            builder: (context, state) {
              return const Home();
            },
            routes: <RouteBase>[
              GoRoute(
                path: 'details',
                builder: (BuildContext context, GoRouterState state) {
                  return const DetailsScreen(tweet_id: 'id');
                },
              ),
            ],
          ),
          GoRoute(
            path: '/search',
            builder: (BuildContext context, GoRouterState state) {
              return const Search();
            },
            routes: <RouteBase>[
              GoRoute(
                path: 'details',
                builder: (BuildContext context, GoRouterState state) {
                  return const DetailsScreen(tweet_id: 'id');
                },
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ],
      ),
    ],
  );
```

My question is that I defined 2 paths for a details screen, '/home/details' and '/search/details', but is this the correct way to create a navigation that I've explained? Do I really need to define a 'details' route in each route ('/home', '/search') even though it reaches the same details page? And if so, do I have to do the same if I add a new tab (e.g. the bookmarks tab), where the user can also navigate to a details page, like:

```
GoRoute
 |-- ShellRoute
      |-- GoRoute(home tab)
      |    |-- GoRoute(details)
      |
      |-- GoRoute(search tab)
      |    |-- GoRoute(details)
      |
      |-- GoRoute(bookmarks tab)
           |-- GoRoute(details)
```

What I actually want is that when the app receives a path like `/details/<tweet-id>`, shows the details page of the specified tweet in the current tab. In other words, if the user is in the home tab, open the details page in the home tab, and if the user is in the search tab, open the details page in the search tab, and so on.

Answer (score 0):

If you are wanting just navigate between 2 views using a navigation bar, you don't need to use routing. That would overcomplicate the application with need to worry about the routing context. The navigation bar works well with view switching internally.

```
class MainWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  MainWidgetState createState() => MainWidgetState();
}

class MainWidgetState extends State<MainWidget> {

    var views = [HomeWidget(), SearchWidget()];
    var currentPageIndex = 0;


    @override
    Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return Scaffold(
            bottomNavigationBar: NavigationBar(
                elevation: 0,
                onDestinationSelected: (int index) {
                setState(() {
                    currentPageIndex = index;
                });
                },
                selectedIndex: currentPageIndex,
                destinations: <Widget>[
                    NavigationDestination(
                        icon: Icon(
                            Icons.home,
                            size: 35.0,
                        ),
                        label: 'Home',
                    ),
                    NavigationDestination(
                        icon: Icon(
                            Icons.search,
                            size: 35.0,
                        ),
                        label: 'Search',
                    ),
                ],
            ),
            body: views[currentPageIndex]
        )
    }
}
```

Comment: Sorry for not being clear enough, but I actually have 5 tabs.  Do you think go_router does not fit in these cases?

Comment: my code would also work for 5 tabs. Routing should really only used when you dont want to preserve the navbar like for a complete new view. so this case the router would not be needed.